# Subform Table Source Show all records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm creating an Access database for data entry, so I put together the form shown in the image below. It works great besides one problems I'm having that I can't seem to nail down.

[image: View of the Form]

I want to create a form that navigates by hiding and un-hiding subforms when clicking the buttons in the top bar. The subforms themselves are linked directly to the table (not a form, but the table itself). I did this in order to have an easy way to enter multiple entries in an excel like fashion that the users are familiar with. Entering the data works fine. Closing the form and re-opening it however causes the subform to show each individual record and the record navigations must be used to cycle through each one.

The intention was for the records be shown in the same fashion as if I just opened the table. Is there any viable way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you investigated changing the form's 'Default View' to be 'Split Form'?

Comment: Yeah, I experimented with split form and changing the recordset of form when a user hits the nav buttons. However, split form auto-collapses each record. A user would have to go through and click the "+" next to each record. I also had a problem with it displaying blank data.

Comment: I replaced the table source as a query and that displays all the data in the format I want. However, this causes a problem with the autofill options.

Comment: Not sure why your split form collapses? Are you saying the 'datasheet' portion at the top is collapsed? I just created a form that toggles the recordsource when you click a button (in the footer) and it formats correctly.  Not sure what you have set as 'Autofill'; what kind of problem?

Comment: No the datasheet portion is appearing. However every line of data is hidden until the expand "+" is clicked to show the data on each line item.

However, the subform is now working as intended so that's not a problem anymore. The data fill seem to be working now as well. I had a problem with the subform linking. Now everything appears to be working great.

Not sure why Access didn't like linking directly to the table, but linking to a query seems to fix it.